# Oracle DBMS jobs in scheduler / SQL deveoper

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following procedure

```
create or replace
procedure test_vinod_cur
is
cursor emp_cur is  select * from test_vino ;
emp_rec test_vino%rowtype;
BEGIN
open emp_cur;
loop
fetch emp_cur into emp_rec;
EXIT WHEN EMP_CUR%NOTFOUND;

insert into test_vino_id values (emp_rec.emp_id,emp_rec.emp_name);
end loop;
CLOSE EMP_CUR;
commit work;
END;
```

How can i schedule this procedure through the DBMS jobs in sql developer window  so that it will run every day at 9 am. Also, if the job fails, how can i find that.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use DBMS_SCHEDULER.SUBMIT_JOB function

Comment: But can u please give me the syntax for that. Am not able to understad from online source since there are many different solutions

Comment: check the answer someone posted below. He has given example of creating a job.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name        => 'INSERT_VINO',
        job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action      => 'test_vinod_cur',
        repeat_interval => 'freq=daily;byhour=9;byminute=00',
        end_date        => NULL,
        enabled         => TRUE);
```

**Attention:** SQL*Plus would *not* run the above because you cannot have a stored procedure call on multiple lines (but I think it's easier to read in this answer and my SQL client does not have this restrictions).

Don't know about SQL Developer, but if it fails, try putting the whole `exec` call on a single line.

More details about the `dbms_scheduler` package can be found in the manual: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI

---

A word about the procedure. The cursor approach is *highly* inefficient, slow and non-scalable. Your procedure can be re-written without a loop or a cursor:

```
create or replace procedure test_vinod_cur
is
BEGIN
  insert into test_vino_id (emp_id, emp_name)
  select emp_id, emp_name 
  from test_vino;
  commit work;
END;
/
```

That will be *much* faster. It is also good coding practice to specify all columns of the target table in the `insert into ...` part.

Comment: Hello, i think this DBMS scheduler...but i expected DBMS jobs

Comment: @VinodChelladurai: `dbms_job` is deprecated and should no longer be used.